# why does this java expression return a negative result?

Tags: java, math, date

```
public static void main (String[] ses) {
    System.out.println(740 * (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
}
```

tried it on google, it gave a different result also on a scientific calculator.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the result is 63,936,000,000 which is more than you can store in a Java integer (which by default those are because none of them are prefaced with L). An integer can only store 4 bytes (32 bits) and that number would require 36 bits. It then overflows, essentially only using the final (first?) 32 bits of the result. Because the first (last? depends on how you look at it) of these bits determines if a number is signed or not, when the number is again actually treated like an integer, it is displayed as negative.

This is particularly useful for calculating hashes, as the only logical alternative I see is to make all numbers over the max value equal to the max value, which I think we can agree is a poor choice.

If you made it `System.out.println(740L * (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));` it should use a long which can store much larger numbers.

You'll note I have question marks through this - bytes are bytes, and bits are bits. What really matters is how you interpret them. There is contention in the software development community what it really means to be the first digit, bit, or byte. Consider "1234" as a number. Is 1 the first digit? Most common folk would agree it is, because it's written first when we look at it. But others would consider 4 to be the first digit, because it's convenient to do so for calculation purposes. (Consider adding - where do you add first? Wouldn't that be the first number?)

So that's why I appear to be indecisive as I say first/last - I just want to make it clear what's going on.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but rather than first/last bit, people often talk about high/low bit or most/least significant bit, for exactly the reasons you describe. The sight bit (the one that says if it's positive or negative) is the most significant bit. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_significant_bit

Comment: @yshavit That's true - but I wouldn't expect someone who doesn't know about integer overflow to grok MSB/LSB, so I tried to put it in terms I know I can work with, which means decimal represented strings.

Comment: @glowcoder fair enough, but if this is going to be the accepted answer, I figured a mention of msb is warranted at least in the comments. :)  (Btw, for posterity: my previous comment had a typo -- "sight bit" should be "sign bit")

Comment: @yshavit that's a fair point. I'm not even opposed to you editing MSB into the answer - SO is intended to be collaboratively edited! And I wouldn't worry about typos. I'm surprised I made it through four questions in a row with no significant typos to speak of this late! :)

Answer (score 2):

all values are being treated as java int type which handles 10 digits while the answer (63 936 000 000) contains 11 digits. If you convert it to long type like

```
System.out.println( Long.valueOf(740) * (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 ));
```

or

```
System.out.println( 740 * Long.valueOf((24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 )));
```

then you will get right answer.

Answer (score 1):

In java, Byte size of int is 4 .Your Calculation exceeds this four bytes values.
so it is throwing some negative value.

It is called Integer overflow.

Answer (score 1):

The Java Language Specification [section 4.2.1](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.2.1) gives the range of values for integral types.

Use this calculation instead:

```
System.out.println(740 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000L);
```

The `L` denotes that 1000 is a `long` primitive (you can use a lowercase L also but that looks too much like a 1 in many fonts). Since 1000 is a `long` the whole answer becomes a `long` - this is known as numeric promotion, specifically a widening conversion from `int` to `long` ([JLS 5.6](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.6)).  The primitive `long` has enough capacity to store the result properly.

It's the same with other numeric types.  Let's say you want a percentage so you write your calculation like this:

```
int i = 99;
System.out.println(i / 100 * 100);
```

`0` will be printed to the screen.  Since all the numbers involved are `int` primitives you'll get 99/100 = 0 because `int` doesn't store the part to the right of the decimal point.

If you divide `i` by a `double` with a value of 100 the calculation will work -  The value 100 is marked as a `double` by the letter 'd':

```
int i = 99;
System.out.println(i / 100d * 100);
```

...giving the expected answer of 99.0.

'i' could have been made the double instead:

```
double i = 99;
System.out.println(i / 100 * 100);
```

...and the answer would still be correct.

Answer (score 0):

When you simply write out calculations like that, Java treats the input values as integers and thus returns an integer.

> (740 * (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) = 63,936,000,000

So it'll try to store 63936000000 in an integer. The problem is, the integer data type isn't designed to store anything higher than 2^32/2-1 = 2,147,483,647. This results in what's called an [Integer Overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow).

Therefore, instead of letting Java guess your data type, you could manually specify a type that allows for a bigger number. In [The Java Tutorial: Primitive Data Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), you can see a list of data types and their limits. Here you'll notice that `long` will fit your needs as it allows for as many as 2^64 different values instead of 2^32.

## So why exactly that number?

If you run your program, you'll get **-488509440**. This is because, as mentioned, the integer data type doesn't allow you to store more than 32 bits. The rest is cut off.

So, the binary representation of **63936000000** is **111011100010111000011111000000000000**. This requires 36-bits, so the first four are cut off. This leaves us with **11100010111000011111000000000000** which in decimal is **3806457856**.

The integer data type uses the first half of all values in 2^32 for the negative values and the second half (minus 1, since we need the value 0 as well) for positive values (hence why you can only store a number as great as 2^32/2-1).

So, if we substract 32^2 from our number, we'll end up with

**3806457856 - 4294967296 = -488509440**.

Comment: It's not a buffer overflow; you won't be reading into any adjacent bytes. It's just integer overflow, meaning that you'll stay within the Integer's 4 bytes, but its value will wrap around. See @Raghuram's link above.